# Which point on the line $Re(z)=1$ under the transformation $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ was sent to $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

The questions asks for me to figure out which point on the line $Re(z)=1$ under the transformation $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ was sent to $0$. 
I know that image is a circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$ however I am confused as to whether $\exists z$ such that $\frac{1}{z} = 0$ as this impossible however since the circle is of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ it leads me to think there must be some point which is mapped there.

Comment: That point would be $\infty$.

Comment: $\lim_{Im(z)\to\infty}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the point on the line $\operatorname{Re}(z)=1$ be $1+ix$. Then under the transformation $f(z)=\frac 1z$, we observe that $f(1+ix) = \left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)+i\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right) = 0$ suggests $x \rightarrow \infty$